# AsBuffer() for sbyte[]?

Tags: c#, .net, byte, uwp

I'm working on a small task that requires me to create IBuffer instances from byte arrays.

With regular byte arrays, the `.AsByte()` extension method from System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime works just fine, however many of my arrays are actually `sbyte[]` (code is ported legacy Java code, where some of the values are defined as e.g. `new sbyte[] { -86, 27, 28, 29, -1 };`

Is there an extension method that covers the `sbyte[]` use case too? Unfortunately not much information is available about sbyte array operations (and conversion into byte arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this conversion method before `AsBuffer()`

```
var signedBytes = new sbyte[] { -86, 27, 28, 29, -1 };
IBuffer buffer = Array.ConvertAll(signedBytes, b => (byte)b).AsBuffer();
```

[Array.ConvertAll Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx)

This method was introduced in .NET 2.0 and exists in all version after that.

> Namespace: System
>
> Assembly: mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)

EDIT:

After further chatting it seems that this code lives in a `Class Library (Portable)` not a regular `Class Library` so `ConvertAll` is not available.

Can achieve the above with this version.

```
var signedBytes = new sbyte[] { -86, 27, 28, 29, -1 };
IBuffer buffer = signedBytes.Cast<byte>().ToArray().AsBuffer();
```

Comment: For some reason, the ConvertAll Array extension method does not exist. Can you specify where it is defined?

Comment: Also I was hoping it was obvious from the tags that I'm working in UWP :)

Comment: I updated my answer to include the documentation and the Namespace/Assembly.

Comment: It is included, but for some reason the ConvertAll method does not exist on the Array class, either as a static method or on an instance.

Comment: That's weird. Is your code in a regular library project or are you doing something else?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. It's a regular PCL targeting profile 259, but this method does not appear in pure UWP implementations either. Might be something going wrong on my end though...

Comment: Interesting. Just as a heads up in the future you should probably state in your question that you are using the Class Library (Portable). Lett me look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert `sbyte[]` to `byte[]` and after that use the other method. Here an example.

```
sbyte[] signed = { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 };
byte[] unsigned = (byte[]) (Array)signed;
```